# hourly weather forecast using openweathermap api

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit

I am trying to fetch hourly forecast data  from openweathermap api from using this url http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=London&APPID using retrofit library but this url not working..

Api interface class

```
public interface ApiInterface {
@GET("forecast?")
Call<HourlyWeather> getHourlyWeather(@Query("q") String city,
                                     @Query("units") String units,
                                     @Query("APPID") String appId);
```

}

api client class

```
public class ApiClient {
public static final String BASE_URL="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/";
public static Retrofit retrofit =null;

public static Retrofit getRetrofit(){
    if (retrofit == null){

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;

}
```

}

retrofit response

```
ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getRetrofit().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<HourlyWeather> call = apiInterface.getHourlyWeather("London","metric",getResources().getString(R.string.api_key));
    call.enqueue(new Callback<HourlyWeather>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<HourlyWeather> call, Response<HourlyWeather> response) {
            Log.d("Hourly","Status code "+response.code());
             list = response.body().getList();

           hourlyTxt.setText(getString(R.string.hourly_forecast));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<HourlyWeather> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

Logcat error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Expected an int but was 1035.16 at line 1 column 138 path $.list[0].main.pressure
03-25 18:41:17.789 16913-16913/com.example.prem.weatherapp W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.read(TypeAdapters.java:245)
03-25 18:41:17.789 16913-16913/com.example.prem.weatherapp W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.read(TypeAdapters.java:235)
03-25 18:41:17.789 16913-16913/com.example.prem.weatherapp W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
03-25 18:41:17.789 16913-16913/com.example.prem.weatherapp W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
03-25 18:41:17.789 16913-16913/com.example.prem.weatherapp W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
03-25 18:41:17.789 16913-16913/com.example.prem.weatherapp W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
03-25 18:41:17.789 16913-16913/com.example.prem.weatherapp W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
03-25 18:41:17.789 16913-16913/com.example.prem.weatherapp W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
03-25 18:41:17.789 16913-16913/com.example.prem.weatherapp W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
03-25 18:41:17.789 16913-16913/com.example.prem.weatherapp W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
03-25 18:41:17.789 16913-16913/com.example.prem.weatherapp W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
03-25 18:41:17.789 16913-16913/com.example.prem.weatherapp W/System.err:     at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:37)
03-25 18:41:17.789 16913-16913/com.example.prem.weatherapp W/System.err:     at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:25)
03-25 18:41:17.790 16913-16913/com.example.prem.weatherapp W/System.err:     at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:118)
03-25 18:41:17.790 16913-16913/com.example.prem.weatherapp W/System.err:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:212)
03-25 18:41:17.790 16913-16913/com.example.prem.weatherapp W/System.err:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:106)
03-25 18:41:17.790 16913-16913/com.example.prem.weatherapp W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:135)
03-25 18:41:17.790 16913-16913/com.example.prem.weatherapp W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
03-25 18:41:17.790 16913-16913/com.example.prem.weatherapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
03-25 18:41:17.790 16913-16913/com.example.prem.weatherapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
03-25 18:41:17.790 16913-16913/com.example.prem.weatherapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
03-25 18:41:17.790 16913-16913/com.example.prem.weatherapp W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Expected an int but was 1035.16 at line 1 column 138 path $.list[0].main.pressure
03-25 18:41:17.790 16913-16913/com.example.prem.weatherapp W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextInt(JsonReader.java:1196)
03-25 18:41:17.790 16913-16913/com.example.prem.weatherapp W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.read(TypeAdapters.java:243)
03-25 18:41:17.790 16913-16913/com.example.prem.weatherapp W/System.err:    ... 20 more
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: hourly data not display and also response code in logcat

Comment: please show the log output

Comment: no data of response code @NinoHandler

Comment: status code 200 not showing me in this particular url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting an int but a double is received for main.pressure.

```
NumberFormatException: Expected an int but was 1035.16
```